# LXC start/stop hangs and filesystem sync hangs

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, lxc

**edit: The issue was my umask being set to 027 rather than the default of 022. See below for details.**

I'm experiencing a bewildering (set of) issues regarding LXC that manifests itself throughout the system after occurring.

When starting/stopping LXC containers, occasionally the start or stop will hang indefinitely. When this happens on startup, the container's `init` process is running but unkillable, even using `kill -9`. The container never comes online, and the only way to end the process is a system reboot.

Thing is, the system won't reboot any more either. At the same time as this issue I noticed an issue when running `update-initramfs`, that also hangs indefinitely. After finding this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428001/update-initramfs-hangs-on-debian-stretch
I have concluded that indeed the `sync` command (both the utility and system call) are hanging, causing LXC to not work, `update-initramfs` to hang, and system shutdown to hang (as a `sync` should be done before unmounting filesystems). Once the issue occurs, calling `sync` (the utility) from the command line will consistently hang indefinitely. I have tried running it in `strace` but the trace ends when going into the kernel call and I can't debug further. I've monitored the caches using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48235/can-i-watch-the-progress-of-a-sync-operation) but it just hovers in the <100kB range.

Considering `sync` has to do with filesystems I expect there is something wrong with the way LXC is handling some filesystem. I have another identical server that does not use LXC, and after comparing the output of `mount` I unmounted the filesystems not present on that one, to no avail. `sync` continues to hang.

Now, on a clean boot, and not touching LXC, `sync` **always** works, and continues to work. For this reason and the fact that I'm not seeing other problems I am positive there are no actual I/O issues. Also when a container does start succesfully, it doesn't seem to have any problems.

I have scoured the internet far and wide regarding this issue, with no success.

LXC 2.0.7-2+deb9u2 on Debian 9 (stable) with kernel 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (although it happened in other recent kernels too), with 2 SSD's in raid1 for `/` and 3 HDD's in raid5 (mdadm) for `/home`. Guests are Debian 9 (stretch) or 10 (buster), running as unprivileged containers. **I seem to have narrowed it down to this: The issue did not occur for privileged containers.**

Example guest container config:

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download

# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.userns.conf
lxc.arch = linux64

# Container specific configuration
lxc.id_map = u 0 200000 100000
lxc.id_map = g 0 200000 100000

# Network configuration
#lxc.network.type = empty
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:e9:4a:e7
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/somename/rootfs
lxc.rootfs.backend = dir
lxc.utsname = somename

# Mounts
lxc.mount.entry = /var/lib/lxc/temp mnt/temp none bind 0 0
```

and subuid/gid mappings:

```
# cat /etc/s*id
root:100000:1000000000
root:100000:1000000000
```

Example container creation, startup, and failing stop:

```
# lxc-create -n test -t download
...
Distribution: debian
Release: stretch
Architecture: amd64

Downloading the image index
Downloading the rootfs
Downloading the metadata
The image cache is now ready
Unpacking the rootfs

---
You just created a Debian stretch amd64 (20190522_05:24) container.

# lxc-ls -f
NAME          STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4 IPV6 
test          STOPPED 0         -      -    -    

# lxc-start -n test

# lxc-ls -f
NAME          STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4 IPV6 
test          RUNNING 0         -      -    -    

# lxc-attach -n test
root@test:/# ls -alh /
total 68K
drwxr-xr-x  21 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:26 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K Mar 28 09:12 boot
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root     400 May 22 09:26 dev
drwxr-xr-x  42 root   root    4.0K May 22 09:24 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K Mar 28 09:12 home
drwxr-xr-x   9 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 225 nobody nogroup    0 May 22 09:26 proc
drwx------   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root      60 May 22 09:26 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:26 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 nobody nogroup    0 May 19 17:07 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root   root    4.0K May 22 05:25 var
root@test:/# exit

# lxc-ls -f
NAME          STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4 IPV6 
debian_buster STOPPED 0         -      -    -    
rtorrent      STOPPED 0         -      -    -    
test          RUNNING 0         -      -    -    

# lxc-stop -n test
^C

# lxc-stop -n test
... continues to hang ...
# ^C
# sync
^C^C^Z^X^C^Z^X^C^Z^C^Z^X^C
... won't die.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was my less-permissive-than-default umask. Debian's default is 022, which I have changed in my user account's `.bashrc` to 027 for security reasons. Upon using `su` to become root, this umask is copied such that all `lxc-*` commands are executed with umask 027. However, this results in a known issue with LXC, which for some reason still hasn't been fixed (in the Debian packages, at least?).

Changing the umask (in session or by modifying the `.bashrc`) allows me to run the containers I already had just fine.

Resources:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/cannot-stop-unprivileged-container-not-even-kill-9-its-systemd-process-on-host/1079

https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/2277 (not sure this is the same issue)

https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/1403

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1642767